# How to properly define and process paramerterized error messages in Java?

Tags: java, string, internationalization, error-handling, properties

**Examples**

I have seen .properties files with a convention similar to the following:

Example 1:

```
error.connection="Could not connect to host {0}, with IP address: {1}"
```

Example 2:

```
error.connection="Could not connect to host %s, with IP address: %s."
```

(and XML files like the following) Example 3:

```
<Error id="connection">Could not connect to host {0}, with IP address {1}</Error>
```

The error message defined in example 2 could be processed like this:

```
// Get error.connection value from .properties file and store it in a variable named ERROR_MESSAGE.
String errorMessage = String.format(ERROR_MESSAGE, hostname, ipAddress);
```

This approach seems unwieldy and dangerous, as it requires the user of the error message to know how many variables the message string requires when when calling `String.format`

**Questions**

What is the best practice (including available tools) for defining and processing variable error messages? 
What is this practice called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Tutorial suggests to use MessageFormat:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/messageFormat.html

You still need to know the order of the arguments, but usually a single message is used only at one place. If you need the same message at more than one place you can wrap the call with a method and strongly typed arguments.